# Self closing XML tags in Access VBA using MSXML

Tags: ms-access, vba, msxml, msxml6

I have been toying around with using Microsoft XML, v6.0 in Access VBA. My question is, is there anyway when writing VBA to create an XML output to have the output have self closing tags?

Like in the following code, when the field is created it will put the text between two tags
I would like for it to have the text in a self closing tag

`<field> name='Unit' value='TEST'</field>` is how it exports

`<field name='Unit' value='TEST'/>` is how I would like it to export

```
Set objMemberName = objDom.createElement("field")
    objMemberElem.appendChild objMemberName
    objMemberName.Text = "name='UNIT' value='TEST'"
```

Answer (score 1):

The following code seems to do what you want:

```vbs
Option Compare Database
Option Explicit

Public Sub test()
    Dim objDom As MSXML2.DOMDocument, objElement As MSXML2.IXMLDOMElement

    Set objDom = New MSXML2.DOMDocument
    Set objElement = objDom.createElement("field")
    objElement.setAttribute "name", "UNIT"
    objElement.setAttribute "value", "TEST"
    objDom.appendChild objElement
    objDom.Save "C:\Users\Gord\Desktop\test.xml"
    Set objElement = Nothing
    Set objDom = Nothing
End Sub
```

When I open "test.xml" I see

```xml
<field name="UNIT" value="TEST"/>
```